# Python SpeechRecognition error

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am exploring speech recognition and came across this python library called [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/). I am running a linux mint system and have followed the troubleshooting steps on the webpage linked above. However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 268, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I also do understand that the KeyboardInterrupt part of the error is from my doing, pressing ctrl+c.

Comment: What kind of console/environment are you using to execute your code? Could your environment be sending the ctrl-c signal?